# Trigger that is only executed once at the end of a transaction

Tags: postgresql, triggers, transactions

How can you program a trigger in PostgreSQL that is only called once at the end of a transaction as soon as a table x has been changed for which the trigger was defined? So the trigger should not fire for every row, nor for every statement, but only once, as soon as all statements of a transaction have been executed.

(The background is, I would like to save a time stamp for some tables when they were last changed.)

Comment: There is no such trigger type.

Comment: The best you can do is a deferred statement level trigger.

Comment: how would i have to define this trigger? like this: ?
create trigger NAME after insert or update or delete on X deferrable for each statement execute …